# How to derive the message from ECDSA Signature value

Tags: php, signature, public-key, ecdsa

Is there any way to derive the message from ECDSA Signature value, like online tools or with PHP for test only,
because I have this Signature `MEUCIH+9yjWRCSWYVW1Tk6hLE91iR8NiVetvz17C3k6ZTJo8AiEAiHe6OK7iyxjUVjpU5RKZjgXgWYP5LjdFsoE5GTB4cIA=` and want to know the `message` and `public key` using `PHP` or any online tools just for test.

Comment: With the signature, you cannot retrieve the message and the public key. A digital signature is a technique used to verify the authenticity and integrity of a message. You shall have the signature, the message and the public key. If one is missing, the verification cannot be performed.

Comment: @Spomky-Labs thanks to guide me for the right answer :)